# Remove All Lines except lines with a Specific Word - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have exported a Backup Report that displays Backup Status of servers,  the servers have a Parent Job and Child Job. The status of the Report is only relevant to the lines related to the Parent Job and Child Jobs provide irrelevant information. The Parent Job contains the keyword "Weekly". How can I display the report to only show lines with the word Weekly ,all other lines should be removed. Thanks.

Comment: Probably a regex find and replace in notepad++ should do it :)

Comment: @witherwind _"better"_ is what sense, does your editor can do it with some in-built features ?

Comment: Notepad++ can do that, try using regex.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

1- Assume this is your file and you want to delete all lines which doesn't have "WScript" in it.

[image]

2- Do a regex find as shown below. BookMark all the required lines.
[image]

3- Then remove the unmarked lines
[image]

Comment: Thanks for solution. To filter-out lines based on a string, this requires many keystrokes. Is there a faster way? where view dynamically shows/hides lines based on as-you-type search string.  Application other than Notepad++ will also do

Comment: This is no longer working.  Mark highlights lines, but bookmark is separate.

Answer (score 23):

**Very Simple way**

1. Press CTRL+F and Type the word or pattern.
2. Click on "Find all in Current Document"

[image]

4) You get the filtered lines. Copy them to a new file.

[image]

Comment: great...
just annoying this window stay on top (don't go under)
and it is not a "true window"... I cant bump on a edge to force windows to fix the windows... but with this I can live...
staying on top it must be solved ASAP...
;-=

Comment: Only works on "small" lines. Long lines are truncated.

Answer (score 10):

Pankaj Jaju's answer works great for most situations.  However, if you want a bit more control then there's also the TextFX Characters plugin.

This plug allows for a great slew of things, but one relevant feature is the ability to just copy the keyword string to clipboard and then tell it to **hide/show the lines with/without the clipboard text.**  I've found this to be faster and more convenient than the bookmark feature when i need to hide various combinations of text matches.

[image]

---

To add the TextFX plugin to your notepad++ you can follow these steps.

1. Show plugin manager

[image]

2. Scroll down on the 'Available' tab.  Check the box for 'TextFX Characters' and click the 'Install' button

[image]

Comment: Didn't know the plugin, very helpfull for this and a lot of other things. Thanks!

Comment: Fyi - it seems that this plugin may only be available for the 32-bit npp.  A similar (but much less robust) option for npp64 is the LineFilter3 plugin.